# How To Remove Item from Spinner using another spinner

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I want to remove spinner specific item using other spinner , both spinner are get data from string-array string.xml , such as if i choose kg from one spinner so kg is remove from other spinner

Comment: Are both spinner getting data from the same array ?

Comment: Also if you want a dynamic spinner, you have to create your array directly in your activity, because resources are not editable.

Comment: yes both spinner getting data from same array

Comment: but i also want to add n<sup>3</sup> in item so that why i use resource

Comment: I'm sorry what is `n<sup>3</sup>` ? And as I said you can NOT edit xml arrays. What you can do is get the xml array in your onCreate and store it into a List. Then just follow my answer and it should work

Comment: it's mean 3 is power on n and it's html tag

Comment: yeah it's work but it permantly remove the item , i just want remove when the same item select , if i choose different item so it should come back, bt it's not

Comment: You can modify my answer and store the removed element in a variable. Then when you select another item, re-add the previous removed item (stored in that variable), and remove the new item.

Comment: can you please do the code because i am beginner in android

Comment: Thanks Brother, It's working

Comment: You can validate my answer so people will know that there is a good answer to your question

Comment: And please help me also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767547/how-to-my-app-flashlight-on-when-screen-is-locked?noredirect=1#comment61113195_36767547

Comment: i also want to add data to spinner with the help of other spinner such as if i choose weight in one spinner than data2 arrayList below add kg, gram, carat, and if i choose temprature in spinner than data2 arraList add celcius, farenheight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code to update you spinners :

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
//populate you lists in onCreate

String tempRemovedItem ;


Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data2);

spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           //when item is selected remove it from data2 and update the adapter of the second spinner

           data2.remove(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());

           if(tempRemovedItem != null){
              data2.add(tempRemovedItem);
           }

           tempRemovedItem = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
           adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i also want to add data to spinner with the help of other spinner such as if i choose weight in one spinner than data2 arrayList below add kg, gram, carat, and if i choose temprature in spinner than data2 arraList add celcius, farenheight

Comment: You can do this with the code I gave you, just get the position of the item clicked and creat an if statement. For exemple,  if position = 1, then set a new list to the adapther and notify the adapter with notifySetDataChanged

Comment: yes i did it, i make multiple adapter and asign them in if statement